# STM32 CubeIDE deletes .elf file while debugging

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I am a beginner in stm programming, so please help me.
I am trying to debug my project but every time I have a [missing .elf file problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbYYW.png)

I never had this problem. When I start a new project, .elf file is being created, but when i try to debug it, it deletes. I am using windows version of 1.9.0 CubeIDE.
Please help me.

Comment: `elf` is created when you compile your project. If your project has errors, it won't get compiled.

Comment: Also, you might want to change the name of it to not contain any spaces.